# Does reggaeton generate greater brain activity than classical music?

Tags: medical-science, neurology, music

A 2021 [Exploring Your Mind](https://exploringyourmind.com/reggaeton-generates-greater-brain-activity-than-classical-music/) article claims:

> A group of neurosurgeons conducted a study that demonstrated intense brain activation when participants listened to reggaeton. In fact, it even surpassed classical music in this respect.
>
> A recent study suggests that listening to reggaeton generates greater brain activity than classical music does.

This is based on a paper by Jesus Martín-Fernández et al: *[Music Style Not Only Modulates the Auditory Cortex, but Also Motor Related Areas](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348567427_Music_Style_Not_Only_Modulates_the_Auditory_Cortex_but_Also_Motor_Related_Areas)*

> The whole brain
> analysis showed higher brain activity during reggaeton listening than the other music genres in auditoryrelated
> areas.

Does [reggaeton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reggaeton) trigger higher brain activity that other genres, such as classical?

Comment: The original question slipped in a "Why?" part, but I couldn't find a claim made in the article about *why* Reggaeton might get a different result. I fear I may have missed it - please edit in a quote where they talk about that.